# C++, change values of struct object belonging to a class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have a following struct Car:

```
struct Car {
public:
    integer number;
 Car *right;
  Car(double a, Car *f): number(a),  right(f){}
};
```

And a Road class,defined in .h:

```
class Road
{
public:
    int road_num;
    Car* police;

};
```

For instance, I want to model something like a chain of cars and each car has a pointer to the next car. (I know I could use list, but I am not allowed to, so I thought of something like this).
I want to be able to define the police car (among other cars) on this specific road. And i want to give a number to this police car already in the main and be able to change it afterwards in the member functions of a Road-Class. I have a problem how to excess the Car variable of a Road-Class

In the main:

```
Road road88;

(*(road88.police)).number=33;
```

and then somewhere in the member function of Road-Class something like this:

```
(*police).number=11;
```

I can complite the programm but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I excess the police-Car in road88?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Show us how you're allocating and initializing the `Car` object.

Comment: Most probably you'll need to instantiate the police `Car` correctly (e.g. using `new Car()`).

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize the pointer to the car, so it points to garbage memory. Try:

```
road88.police = new Car;
road88.police->number = 33; // same as (*(road88.police)).number = 33;;
```

It would be better to initialize it in a constructor, though.

Using pointers as fields can be very tricky. I recommend looking into the rule of three and becoming very familiar with the intricacies of dynamic allocation.

Comment: Then once you're familiar with those intricacies, look into RAII and the rule of zero, and never worry about them again.